# Configuring Swagger with values from Iconfiguration object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, swagger-ui

I am trying to configure swagger in startup.cs. If I give its required values "Hardcoded" like below  `in ASP.NET Core : 2.2`

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
      c.SwaggerDoc("V1", new Info { Title = "MY.API", Version ="v1" });
    });

    app.UseSwagger();
    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MY.API V1");
    });
```

but if i set all above hard coded values from "IConfiguration" object provided by asp.net core, then it stop working,

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   c.SwaggerDoc(this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSetting") 
   ["APIName"], new Info { Title = "My.API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the comment but I don't have enough karma.

First please show us your appsettings.json.
Second check that this line actually returns correct value and not null or empty string (just put it in local var):

```
this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSetting")["APIName"]
```

**Edit:**
It seems that name field is case sensitive. Make sure you use value from config also in UseSwaggerUI:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSetting")["APIName"]}/swagger.json", "MY.API V1");
});
```

Comment: Artur : I did that debugging yes it's returning same string, which is passed as hard coded here